# jumpy scrolling in all browsers except Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox, scroll

I haven't noticed until now because I use Firefox 99% of the time, but as I was running some tests on a parallax effect I've noticed how jerky and choppy the scrolling was, basically jumping with every click of the mousewheel.

I thought at fist that this had something to do with the page I was testing but now I realize this happens with every website on all browsers with exception of Firefox.

I'm using windows 8 if that matters...

Is this normal???
If so, is there some fix for a cross browser smooth scrolling?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I use a mac now but when I work on my windows machine it did the same thing. Try searching a plugin called `smooth scrolling` it should fix your issue.

If you don't want a plugin you can check this tutorial out: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/smooth-scrolling/

Plug-in: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/smoothscroll/nbokbjkabcmbfdlbddjidfmibcpneigj?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

@Joe Scotto,

Thanks a lot for your reply. I appreciate it.

I'm familiar with the jquery you mentioned and I use it in several sites but that doesn't address the mouseweel jumpy scrolling issue.

As for the plugin you suggest I couldn't find a way to download it, so I haven't been able to try it, but if it's something that works for Chrome only, it doesn't really solve my problem.

If this issue is something common to all browsers in Windows (except Firefox) then I need something that can provide a good experience to all users no matter what browser they're using. I'm very surprised that I can't find more people concerned with this and even more surprised that modern browsers don't come up with something to fix this. As far as I've been able to find in my research, it seams that Firefox comes with it's own scrolling animation to overcome this issue. The question is why don't others do the same...

At the moment the best solution I could find was this plugin http://bassta.bg/2013/05/smooth-page-scrolling-with-tweenmax/ Changing the settings to make it a bit faster seams to make the scrolling a bit more natural then the one in the demo.

If anyone has a better or simpler solution I would like to hear it.

Thanks.